# How can you use GetType().GetProperties() on a PowerShell Custom PSObject?

Tags: powershell, reflection, log4net, psobject

I am trying to get [this log4net customization](http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/05/mapping-message-object-properties-to.html) to work with PowerShell PSObjects. Basically, this pattern layout will iterate over the object and dump its properties into CSV columns. Here is the code that does the reflection:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = loggingEvent.MessageObject.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
            {
                object value = prop.GetValue(loggingEvent.MessageObject, null);
                loggingEvent.Properties[prop.Name] = value;
            }
```

This works fine when using a normal class in C#. It also works if I create a class using inline C# in PowerShell like this.

```
$code = @”

using System;
namespace CsvTest { 
    public class MyEvent
        {
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public string Details { get; set; }
            public int EventCode { get; set; }

        }
    }
“@

Add-Type $code

$test = New-Object CsvTest.MyEvent
$test.UserId = "Andy"
$test.Details ="SomeStuff"
$test.EventCode = 10

$MyCommonLogger.Error($test)
$MyCommonLogger.Info($test)
$MyCommonLogger.Warn($test)
```

What doesn't work is if I create a custom PSObject. If I replace the $code with a PSCustom object such as

```
$obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                        "UserId" = "Andy";
                        "EventCode" = 100;
                        "Details" = "DetailInfoGoeshere"
                        }
```

Then it will just return Null. I have verified that this does in fact return null.

```
$obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                        "UserId" = "Andy";
                        "EventCode" = 100;
                        "Details" = "DetailInfoGoeshere"
                        }

$obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

I suppose I could hack up CSVLogging Pattern layout and make a special case if the inbound object is a PSObject, but I'd rather not have to customize it for just one type of object. Is there a way in PowerShell to take a psobject and covert/cast it into something that I can use with GetType().GetProperties()?

Comment: What version of powershell, Andy?

Comment: PowerShell v3 on Windows 8

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand, according to the result of :

```
Get-Member -InputObject $obj -Force
```

The ways to get psObject properties are :

```
$obj.psobject.properties
$obj.psobject.get_properties()
```

Can't you write the C# code that dynamicaly create the class ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the code in PowerShell to generate the class I needed.  I added the "Test-IsAssemblyLoaded" function so that it wouldn't attempt to load the same assembly twice in the same PS runsapce. Kind of dirty but works.

```
Function Test-IsAssemblyLoaded {
param ($assembly)

$result = $false
try {
        $expression = "[$assembly]| out-null"
        invoke-expression $expression;
        $result = $true
    } 


catch {$result = $false}

return $result
}


Function Add-DotNetClass {
param(

[Parameter()]
$NameSpace = "PowerShell",

[Parameter()]
$Properties,

[Parameter()]
$ClassName

)

$code = @"

using System;

namespace $Namespace
{
    public class $className 
    {
        $(foreach ($p in $Properties)
                {
    "public $p {get;set;} `n"
                } )

    }
}
"@

if (Test-IsAssemblyLoaded "$Namespace.$ClassName") {Write-Warning "Assembly already loaded"}
else {Add-Type $code}

}
```

It seems to do the trick.